# How to modify audio level of video according to replaygain info?

Tags: audio

I have a bunch of music videos I have downloaded from youtube. I usually put them in a playlist in mpc (Media Player Classic). The problem is that the audio levels of the videos are quite different and I have to adjust the volume for each one.

If I hear them in foobar2000 (it's an audio player) there's no problem because it can apply the replaygain info wich I have added to the videos, but mpc hasn's this feature.

Mpc has a normalization option but it is dynamic and is not what I want.

An aceptable solution would be to recode the video with the audio levels corrected. But I want to move the audio level globally to the video, not dynamic normalization. And also I want to leave the video untouched. What tool can I use?

Answer (score 6):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, has a volume filter that should do this.

Syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -af volume=replaygain=track output.mp4
```

The `af` invokes the `volume` filter with the option set to adjust the volume using the track replaygain value (if present). Video is set to passthrough into the output.

Comment: *"using the track replaygain value (if present)."* - How does one add this `replaygain` value if it is NOT present?

Comment: Maybe I should post another question?